# Use LS055R1SX04 at lower resolution with minimal startx and xrandr

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr

My machine is a Rock Pi 4B+ running Ubuntu Server 20.04. I downloaded minimal startx and also xrandr to run my Rust program that has raylib so that it can actually display renders on my LS055R1SX04 LCD. The issue is that my Rock Pi is not capable of rendering that 1440x2560 at not even above 10 fps so I had to lower it. I have already been using xrandr because the LCD is meant for a portrait so I used it to make it landscape, I put a new mode for 1920x1080 at 60fps, configure my raylib to render at 1920x1080, and make sure the xrandr rotation still the left and it did run but nothing showed up on my LCD whatsoever. I used x11vnc to see what really is showing up there and it's just terminal rendering at 1440x2560. When I try to run my program it showed up for a few seconds before going away and returning back to the terminal view. Keep in mind the LCD does support 1920x1080 as I tested with my Windows main computer.